# Cause of greasy gunk accumulation under exhaust headers

Tags: engine, leak, acura, integra

When examining my engine bay earlier, I noticed a large amount of black gunk built up on the bottom part of the engine under the exhaust headers.  I removed the exhaust header heat shield and found the engine block covered in this slimey black residue.

There did not appear to be any oil leaking from the valve cover, but this residue has been there for thousands of miles I just never realized the extent of it.  At one point I have had the head gasket changed so it may have fixed it or made it worse.

What could have caused this? Is there any way to check to make sure I'm not leaking oil and contributing to this accumulation of black gunk?

Comment: What is the year/make/model/engine of the affected vehicle? Also, do you have any pictures? Would help us to understand the extent of what you're talking about and where exactly it is occurring.

Comment: It is a 1994 acura integra ls with a b18b1 engine.  I will attempt to get pictures to clarify

Comment: could be a leaky PCV hose

Comment: It could also be accumulation of road debris + water getting stuck and baked on to the side of the hot engine over time. Any pictures?